# order by hiredate DESC not working as expected in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column `hiredate` in mysql table. I had to choose the datatype for this column as varchar because sometimes I got the values for `hiredate` as 'xxxx-xx-xx' or 'zzzz-zz-zz'and I need to save these values in database.

My problem is that when I execute the query with

```
select distinct
    agentname
from agentdata
where hiredate not in ('xxxx-xx-xx','zzzz-zz-zz')
order by hiredate desc
```

clause, it is not returning the correctly sorted data. But when I execute the query with

```
select distinct
    agentname,
    hiredate
from agentdata
where hiredate not in ('xxxx-xx-xx','zzzz-zz-zz')
order by hiredate desc
```

clause, it  returned the correct sorted data.

The difference is only the `hiredate` field in select statement. I don't know the reason for this behaviour of Mysql.

Comment: The two queries you showed us are different, and don't return the same columns.  Comparing them is somewhat apples to oranges IMO.

Comment: Yes these two are different , so is it mandatory to have the column name in select clause if you want to sort the result set correctly? what if i only want agentname sorted by hiredate? str_to_date(hiredate, '%Y-%m-%d') didnot worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast to date and order by date.

```
ORDER BY str_to_date(hiredate, '%Y-%m-%d')
```